# jQuery isotope with starting large block not working

Tags: jquery-isotope

I've created an isotope page that has a number of different height elements on it. The majority of the elements are the same width, however I would like to be able to start the flow with a 'large' box spanning the first two columns.

Placing larger blocks in the normal layout is fine, provided that isoTope starts with one of the smaller width blocks. However if I put in a larger one, it suddenly puts everything into one column, despite any settings I put into the jQuery statement (such as specifying the column width as 300 wide).

Is there anyone who could look over what I've done and suggest if this is an actual bug or something that I'm missing? I've tried to put the large block at the bottom and then use the sorting functionality to bring it to the top, but the same issues happens.

http://territorydigital.com/mmrs/index.html <- this is with the starting large block
http://territorydigital.com/mmrs/index2.html <- this is just normal blocks with large blocks later

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 4):

Somehow this might work..

Quote from http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html

> Masonry is the default layout mode for Isotope. Item elements are
>   arranged intelligently within a vertical grid. For each item element,
>   the script calculates the next best fit for the item within the grid.
>
> The width of one column in the grid. ***If no value is set for
>   columnWidth, default is the width of the first item element.***

The solution will be

```
$('#container').isotope({
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 1 // or any number smaller than your medium size box/item
  }
});
```

By setting `columnWidth` to `'1'`, it'll force isotope to use the defined `columnWidth` instead of the size of the first element. Hence, justify my answer from earlier reply (deleted :( )

Answer (score 0):

You can now set the column width to a selector, possibly an item just used for finding out the size of things an not included in the layout.  The same is true of gutter.

See here:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#columnwidth